# Looking for a jumpstart to this 'odd' abstract proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Here's the statement:
Let $G$ be a group with $2n$ elements where $n$ is an odd integer, and $H$ is a subgroup with $n$ elements. The product of every element in $G$ (taken in any order) is not in $H$.

The way I see it, the total number of elements in $G$ would be 2(2$k$+1) for some $k \in Z$.  The part I'm not quite getting is how it relates to the product of all the elements in $G$ not being in $H$.  I feel like it has something to do with the size of $G$ compared to $H$ in that there are more numbers in $G$ that don't align with elements in $H$...how can I better understand what's going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The thing you want to prove would follow easily (do you see how?) if only you knew that, whenever $g_1$ and $g_2$ are elements of $G$ which do not belong to $H$, then their product $g_1g_2$ belongs to $H$.

Comment: It often happens that assigned exercises are related to stuff you have just learned. So, have you learned anything recently that could have a bearing on this exercise? Anything about a subgroup of order $n$ in a group of order $2n$?

Comment: @bof Thanks for the heads up, meant to label it as "statement".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that because $[G:H]=2$, $H$ is normal in $G$.  Note also that there are an odd number of elements in $G \setminus H$.  Multiply their representatives *in the quotient group* $G/H \cong \{ e, x \}$, where $x^2=e$.  We're therefore taking an odd power of $x$, so we end up with $x$ again.  Adding to the product elements of $H$ will not change this result, so we conclude that the product of all elements of $G$ cannot be in $H$.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Would you mind elaborating a bit on what you mean by multiplying the representatives?  Does that mean multiply an element in $G$ with an element of $G/H$ and likewise with $H$?

Comment: @BubbyNX note that the product in $G/H $ $$(g_1H)\times ... \times (g_{2n}H)$$ equals $$(g_1\times  ... \times g_{2n})H$$ If the product of all the elements of $G$ belonged to $H$, the previous expression would be $H$ which is the identity $e$ in the quotient group $G/H$. On the other hand, exactly $n$ out of the $2n$ cosets in the first expression are $e$ whereas the other $n$ cosets are the unique non$-$ identity element $x$ in the quotient group. In other words we have $x^n=e$ which is a contradiction.